# What is event for selectbox dynamic change value

Tags: html

here is the code in select box

```
   <select id="localityvalid" onchange="getLocalitiesList('local')>
<option  value="1">hello</option>
   -------------------

 somewhere i did the following dynamically adding `<option selected='selected' value="+results.id+">"+results.value+"</option>`
```

whwn i change select box using dropdown the getLocalitiesList() executed but when i dynamically adding value  is'nt.
 is there any event for that to got acknowledge that method?otherwise how to do that?

if i append new selecbox like

```
 <select id="localityvalid" onchange="getLocalitiesList('local')>
`<option selected='selected' value="+results.id+">"+results.value+"</option>`
```

then i need invoke that method

Comment: Do you mean "onchange"? Or you want to do something while changing the  value?

Comment: <option selected='selected' value="+results.id+">"+results.value+"</option> when this is dynamically create a option so when it is append i wany to execte onchange method

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method lik "getLocalitiesList(this.value);"

- function getLocalitiesList(value){
- alert(value);
- // do what you want(like change some value)
- }

you could get the value you selected.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to trigger that function you need to call it separately right after appending that new dynamic option.

Comment: if i append entire select box with a default selectoption then i want to grigger  that function

Answer (score 0):

Use selectObject.fireEvent('onchange') after dynamically adding value.